# SSH not pointing to latest openssl [Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS -Xenial Xerus]

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, openssh, openssl

I have updated the openssl but still the ssh is not pointing to this version of openssl.

**How I can make ssl and openvpn to point to this version of openssl?**
I tried to google but didnot find anything close. Thats why pointing this here.

```
~$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018

~$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

The actual problem I have is I couldnot connect to a VPC which is using AES-256-GCM. Since the openssl 1.0.2g did not support it. I need to update to the latest version and be able to use openvpn point to the latest version of openssl.